# getElementById is getting null pointer exception

Tags: java, jsoup

my code is getting null pointer exception at content.html(); 
as each time Element content is assign to null 
while i am sure that the page contains the element with that id 
i am using **jsoup** to parse Document 
one can please check the code and catch my mistake

```
public void get_content(String eliment_by,String identification)
{
    try {

        File currentDirectory = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath()+"/tmp/input.html", "UTF-8");
        writer.println(" ");
        writer.close();
        File input = new File(currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath()+"/tmp/input.html");
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", this.curr_url);
        Element content = doc.getElementById(identification);

        this.current_page_content=content.html();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(url_looping.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the html or a snippet and the identification your are searching for?

Comment: ya why no http://www.opengurukul.com/vlc/mod/page/view.php?id=523 and id  identification is "region-main-wrap"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file and writing a space character to it and then read this file for parsing. When you use `PrintWriter` this clears your file. So what happens here is first you clear the file and then trying to parse it. That is why null pointer

if you want to get that from url you could do like

```
public void get_content(String eliment_by, String identification) {
    try {

        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.opengurukul.com/vlc/mod/page/view.php?id=523").get();
        Element content = doc.getElementById(identification);

        this.current_page_content = content.html();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(url_looping.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have commented this 3 line but no change                        // PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath()+"/tmp/input.html", "UTF-8");
           // writer.println(" ");
           // writer.close();

Comment: If you comment out these 3 lines then that should work. Provided the input.html does have a valid html with id as mentioned. I just tested it and it works.

Comment: thanks it just worked perfectly without the first 6 line